# Не получается грамотно задать переменную среды в Windows

Tags: golang, protoc

Имя "protoc" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы.
Пробовал:
%USERPROFILE%\go\bin\protoc-gen-go-grpc
C:...\go\bin\protoc-gen-go-grpc
%USERPROFILE%\go\bin
C:...\go\bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задать переменную среды в Windows

```
set path="%path%;c:\dir1\dir2"
```